# swift iOS , location manager startUpdatingLocation in background when didEnterRegion

Tags: ios, swift, location

I would like to start updating the location (didUpdateLocations should be called every meter or so) after a geo fence enter event (didEnterRegion) for a certain time. That all in the background so I do have:
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

But for some reason didUpdateLocations is only called for about 10 seconds after the didEnterRegion event.
When I start my app with startUpdatingLocation and allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true, didUpdateLocations is called every meter or so for unlimited time. But obviously I can´t have it running in the background all time since it will drain the battery in no time.

Any ideas?
Many Thanks
Stephan

Comment: If you enable significant location hanged monitoring in the foreground then you can start/stop location updates in the background without the updates ending after a short time

Comment: That´s a bummer :-( Thanks for the answer Paulw11!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution for that?